# Intellij is showing errors for dependencies even when project is building fine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am fairly new to intellij and I am having a hard time understanding on how to set up the project structure of my project.

I have a multi-module project when a root pom and a few child poms. BUt somehow intellij is recognising some of the dependencies and not recognizing others. follow image:
[image]

I tried to correct my project structure but without any success. Following is the present look of my project structure.

[image]

Library settings:

[image]

Comment: Please attach screenshot of this library, opened in File | Project Structure | Libraries settings.

Comment: @Andrey added library screenshot

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the jar file is found. And could you please attach a screenshot of such broken library expanded in Project tool window **External Libraries** node?

Comment: As a workaround it could help to re-import project via File | New | Project from Existing Sources action to re-create project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after a lot of trouble. The issue was that the poms of the sub projects were somehow marked as ignored.

[image]

As soon as removed them from ignored the issue was resolved